# Hide root site in Multisite install

Tags: multisite, domain-mapping, configuration

I recently setup a WordPress multisite install using subdomains and the WordPress MU domain mapping plugin.

When I initially setup the domain mapping plugin, I set the root (http://domain.com) and http://www.domain.com to redirect to blog ID 2 (ie. www.domain.com). However, when I do this the redirect on the root prevents me from accessing the Network admin page.

Is there a way I can change the configuration to enable me to still access the Network admin page whilst redirecting the root site to www?

Comment: Can you remove the redirection from the domain mapping plugin, and place redirection of non-www to www in .htaccess using normal rewrite rules?

Comment: Shouldn't this part read like: "blog ID 2 (ie. www.`another-domain`.com)"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was in a similar situation recently. I ended up putting the root site on a random subdomain (eg `ms.domain.com`)  With the intention of never using the root site.

With that done, I created a plugin to activate only on the main (root) site.

The plugin hooks into a action that fires only on the front end (`template_redirect`).  From there, call `wp_redirect` to send your visitors to where they need to be.

```
<?php
add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse52298_redirect');
/*
 * Redirects all requests to the front end to another site
 *
 * @uses wp_redirect
 */
function wpse52298_redirect()
{
    // change this
    $to = 'http://www.example.com';

    wp_redirect(esc_url($to));
    exit();
}
```

**Cons:**

- Loads basically all of WP before redirecting
- Not as fast as redirecting in htaccess

**Pros:**

- Easy to maintain
- No htaccess foo required

As a [plugin](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/WPSE-Plugins/blob/master/redirect-site.php).

Comment: Thanks Chris! I believe this is a better approach than creating a custom theme or editing `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using this solution:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/$
Rewriterule ^(.*)$ http://mysecondsite.com/ [L,R=301]
```

as it preserves the root domain's subdirectories, allowing you to manage the multisite admin dashboard.

Source: [How to redirect root and only root via htaccess?](https://serverfault.com/questions/58762/how-to-redirect-root-and-only-root-via-htaccess#58787)